# Trash/delete screenshots before Cypress runs via npx cypress open

Tags: reactjs, cypress

According to Cypress docs, you can trash screenshots when using `cypress run`. However, when I am using the UI with `npx cypress open` then clicking the Run button I would like to do the same. Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does not record videos or screenshots during `cypress open`, so there will be nothing to trash.

Comment: If I put cy.screenshot() https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot.html in my test it will save to the screenshots folder. If I press the Run button multiple times the screenshots folder will put more screenshots without deleting the old ones.

Comment: This information was not in the original post.  You are correct in that if `cy.screenshot()` is present in tests it will save to the screenshots folder.  There as not been a feature request for this functionality.  Please feel free to open a feature request in the cypress GitHub repo.